# Gradients are not smoothly rendered

Tags: rendering

I'm doing a small video in which I want a gradient as background. I'm doing it with a plane, with a gradient texture (with the ramp and type "blend"). Everything is well rendered with the UV/Image Editor, but when i'm rendering my video (with H.264 lossless codec), the gradient gets full of stripes of irregular width, I can't get it smooth.

I tried to change the lightning, used a picture of that gradient instead of the precalculate one, tried to "smooth" the plane structure, to modify anti-aliasing display, but nothing work.

Does anyone had this problem and know what to do ?

Thank you guys !

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/29218/how-to-avoid-gradient-banding-while-using-a-video-sequence-editor. Try searching dithering on this site as well.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6488/spotlight-with-halo-applied-is-creating-rings-around-light and: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5795/what-does-dither-do-in-cycles/5800#5800 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9279/how-to-make-a-dithering-effect-in-blender/9280#9280